# How to edit my compare products

Tags: magento-1.9, compare

I have my comparable products page in a table.
In my fist row there is Description.
In my 3rd row there is SKU
I want to move my SKU in the first row

How to achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attributes that are displayed in the compare list are retrieved in the method `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Compare_Item_Collection::getComparableAttributes` but this method does not sort the attributes in any way.
So they are retrieved in the way that mysql wants it. Which is not very predictable.
You can take the result of that method and try to parse the result and rearrange the attributes as you want, or you can override the method and after the line `->where('main_table.attribute_id IN(?)', $attributeIds)` add this

```
->order(new Zend_Db_Expr('CASE WHEN main_table.attribute_code = "sku" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END DESC'));
```

Comment: but i cant find the line" ->where('main_table.attribute_id IN(?)', $attributeIds)" in list.phtml

Comment: it's not in list.phtml. It's in `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Compare_Item_Collection`

Comment: is there any way to edit compared product page without touching mage files?

Comment: yes...rewrite the class properly. There are a lot of docs on how to rewrite a resource model.

Comment: Is there any link to study about that? pls help me

Comment: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=magento+rewrite+resource+model